# Reducing and fixing a top margin in a formal letter by several centimetres (Overleaf)

Tags: letters

I'm currently tweaking a template for formal letters and I'd like to manually reduce and fix the top margin by a few centimeters to the top, so that my university logo and the beginning of my letter start further above than where they're currently displayed. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this. Do you know what kind of code would be required?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{letter} % Set the font size (10pt, 11pt and 12pt) and paper size (letterpaper, a4paper, etc)

\input{structure.tex} % Include the file that specifies the document structure

\longindentation=0pt % Un-commenting this line will push the closing "Sincerely," and date to the left of the page

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=7cm}

\usepackage{tgbonum}

\usepackage{graphics} %package to include images%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   YOUR INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\Who{Cameron Morin \\} % Your name

\Title{Doctorant contractuel, Linguistique \\ Université de Paris - CLILLAC-ARP } % Your title, leave blank for no title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADER CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\logo{UNIVERSITE_PARIS_LOGO} % Logo filename, your logo should have square dimensions (i.e. roughly the same width and height), if it does not, you will need to adjust spacing within the HEADER STRUCTURE block in structure.tex (read the comments carefully!)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000 %Justifies the text without hyphenation

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}

{\fontfamily{cmu}\selectfont 

\opening{Objet: candidature à une bourse mobilité région Ile-de-France

\vspace{5mm}Madame, Monsieur, 

Je vous adresse...

Mon projet de thèse...

Ce séjour..

Espérant ...

 \\[2\baselineskip]

\closing{Bien cordialement,} }

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{MORIN_SIGNATURE.png}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I insert this to overleaf I get errors. Please provide a working MWE. Have you tried the `\vskip` command?

Comment: hi, here's the link if you'd like to see the details : https://www.overleaf.com/project/5eb5570b82d94500017b0058

Comment: I've tried vskip but it doesn't do anything. That said I'm not sure of how it works. PS: what does MWE stand for?

Comment: Minimum working example. I also can't follow your link, it says 'Restricted, ...'. Please adapt your post that it's self contained. Hence, that we can copy code directly into an editor and it works straigth away.

Comment: Just turned on sharing in Overleaf, does it work now ? https://www.overleaf.com/6748297978zkttxbpvtxcm

Comment: Not sure what you mean by adapting my post to self contained?

Comment: This link can break (e.g. if you delete it from overleaf). The question should be stated in a way, that everyone else, who searches it (probably years later) can find it and reproduce it. Hence, if someone would copy your code, there will be errors when compiling. This should be avoided. So please produce code which is as small as possible to show your issue. Furthermore, this code has to compile without any problem without any extra work for everyone else. This eases also the help. There are e.g. two tex files nested, both of them define the `\geometry`. Please clean up

Comment: Ok, thanks I understand now ! Only problem is that I don't know what the errors are on your side

Comment: I created the letter from the UNSW formal letter template on Overleaf, which has a main.tex file and a structure.tex file. I also have two .pngs, one for my logo and one for my signature.

Comment: Basically it appears that the top of the letter starts at the centre when there is no text, and as I add text it goes up a bit. But I'd like to extend the upper limit to x cm (e.g. 1 cm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/unsw-formal-letter-template/bycnqqtpjhvj) template is used, the margin at the top can be reduced when changing the `top=-5cm` property inside the `\geometry` definitions. Note, make sure that you don't redefine the `\geometry` somewhere else again but only at one place. Also note, that the distance can be negative too.